# get real class name for cdi managed bean

Tags: java, cdi

Is there a way to get hold of the real class name for a CDI managed instance?
I need the real class name to match on it, but I get Client Weld Proxy names when invoking getClass method.
much appreciated.

Comment: Is the interface acceptable, or do you want the concrete class it is proxying?

Comment: The interface is good too, in my case I have concrete classes that is wrapped in CDI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I could understand there is not reliable way to get a hold of real class behind the proxy. As a matter of fact there might not be a real class after all.
What I ended up doing is to check the classname string to see it it matches the crazy string Weld attaches to class name. If it is not, then you are dealing with the real class. But if it is, get the superclass of the proxy. That is the class you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Even though it has been five years since the original question, this might help someone who might come across the same problem. You can get the real class name using reflection.

```
bean.getClass().getSuperclass().getName()
```

works with Weld

Comment: This works with Weld as the proxies it generates are a subclass of the original class. While it works with Weld, it may not work with other implementations depending on how it proxies classes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look into the Weld implementation to see if the InvocationHandler will actually give it to you if you getInvocationHandler and then call the method.